# How do I drop all nodes which are connected with particular edge?

Tags: gremlin

Consider I have the following path:

`A --- dependsOn --> B --- dependsOn --> C --- dependsOn --> D`

I want to drop all dependent nodes `A,B,C` if I start from `C`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `C` should be dropped too:

```
g.V(C).emit().repeat(__.in('dpendsOn')).drop()
```

And if you only want to drop the vertices on the left of side of `C`:

```
g.V(C).repeat(__.in('dpendsOn')).emit().drop()
```

Comment: Could you pleas explain, why `emit()` is placed after `repeat` in the second query, but is absent in the first one?

Comment: It's not absent in the first query, it comes before `repeat`. You place it in front of `repeat()` if you want to emit the first element that goes in (in your case `C`).

Comment: Yes, but why then there is no `emit` after `repeat` in the first query whereas it exist in the second one after `repeat`?

Comment: It's either before (to emit the first element) or after (to skip the first element) repeat, you can't have both.